# How can I check if an XML element exists inside another element in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, xml

Here is my XML code, what I would like to do is check that within the `<testcase>` element there is the `<failure>` element with an if to put conditions.

```
<testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="1" tests="20" time="102.012">
   <testsuite name="name1" timestamp="2021-01-27T10:20:51" hostname="localhost" time="79.312" errors="0" tests="12" skipped="1" disabled="0" failures="1">
      <testcase classname="nametescase" name="STEP_1: Date filter" time="3.776">
         <failure></failure>
      </testcase>
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

How can I do this condition in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) in Nodejs with the following packages: [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom) and [xpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath)

A simple example

```js
var xpath = require('xpath')
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser

const xml = `
<testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="1" tests="20" time="102.012">
   <testsuite name="name1" timestamp="2021-01-27T10:20:51" hostname="localhost" time="79.312" errors="0" tests="12" skipped="1" disabled="0" failures="1">
      <testcase classname="nametescase" name="STEP_1: Date filter" time="3.776">
         <failure></failure>
      </testcase>
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
`

const doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml);
var failureNode = xpath.select("//testcase/failure", doc); //<--- xpath
console.log(failureNode.length);
```